# Alpinejs property bound to x-show not defined

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, alpine.js

I'm building a form in Laravel's Blade syntax, and using AlpineJs for some interactivity stuff like showing and hiding content.

My code is here:

```
<div class="flex items-center" x-data="destinationBuilder">
    <x-label required="true" class="mr-5">Destination:</x-label>
    <x-basic-input @change="handleDestinationChange" ::value="destination" placeholder="https://google.com"/>
    <x-buttons.primary class="ml-5" @check="validateDestination">Check</x-buttons.primary>
</div>
<div class="mt-4">
    <button type="button"
            class="p-5 w-full text-sm grid grid-cols-[min-content_min-content_auto_min-content] items-center gap-x-3 font-light text-gray-400 hover:bg-gray-300 rounded-full"
            @click.camel="toggleAdvancedOptions">
        <i class="lni lni-cog"></i>
        <span class="whitespace-nowrap">Advanced options</span>
        <div class="h-px w-full bg-gray-400"></div>
        <i class="lni lni-chevron-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div x-show="advanced" x-transition x-cloak>
{{--        <x-links.get-parameter-form/>--}}
    </div>
</div>

@push('footer-scripts')
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
            Alpine.data('destinationBuilder', () => ({

                destination: '',

                advanced: false,

                handleDestinationChange() {
                    if (this.validateDestination()) {
                        // emit constructed destination up
                    }
                },

                validateDestination() {
                    // check url is in a legit form (with https)
                    // basic is just url input
                    // advanced dropdown with get parameters, fragment, http protocol and port
                },

                toggleAdvancedOptions() {
                    this.advanced = !this.advanced;
                }

            }));
        })
    </script>
@endpush
```

I'm using a property named `advanced` to bind to x-show for another component.

When I look in my browser I get the following message: `app.js:434 Uncaught ReferenceError: advanced is not defined`

I'm not sure if this is due to a weird collision with blade or if I'm missing something fundamental with Alpinejs. I tried renaming the variable to `showAdvanced` but that didn't work either. I would expect advanced to be recognised as a property and bind to x-show as expected. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the following HTML structure:

```
<div x-data="destinationBuilder">
...
</div>
<div>
    <div x-show="advanced">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

As you see, the second div is not a child element of the first one where the `x-data` is defined, so it's outside of the scope of `destinationBuilder` component. Just create a common div (or similar) element that embeds both divs and apply the component `x-data` there, so each div will have access to the component's scope.